# How to Replace Values Exceeding Threshold with Random Number Sampled from a Given Dataset?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, sample, replacewith

I have a 3-dimensional vector called 'simulatedReturnsEVT3'. In that vector, I would like to replace all values that are higher than 'MaxAcceptableVal' or lower than 'MinAcceptableVal'. Such values that are beyond either of these two thresholds should be replaced by a random number that is drawn from the 3-dimensional vector 'data2'. For drawing that random number, I use the matlab function 'datasample'.

I have written the below code, which replaces the values that are beyond either of the thresholds with a random number sampled from 'data2'. However, it seems (when plotting the data in a histogram) that the replacement happens with the same value along dimension 'j'. This is not what I want to do. For every threshold exceedance, I want a new random number to be drawn for replacement from 'data2'.

```
nIndices = 19
nTrials  = 10000

% data2                has dimensions 782 x 19 x 10000
% simulatedReturnsEVT3 has dimensions 312 x 19 x 10000
% MaxAcceptableVal     has dimensions   1 x 19
% MinAcceptableVal     has dimensions   1 x 19

% Cut off Outliers
for i=1:nIndices
    for j=1:nTrials
        sliceEVT = simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j);
        sliceEVT(sliceEVT < MinAcceptableVal(i))=datasample (data2(:,i,j), 1,1,'Replace',false);
        sliceEVT(sliceEVT > MaxAcceptableVal(i))=datasample (data2(:,i,j), 1,1,'Replace',false);
        simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j) = sliceEVT;
    end
end
```

The same problem can be illustrated on a smaller scale by creating the following matrices.

```
% Set Maximum Acceptable Levels for Positive and Negative Returns
MaxAcceptableVal = [0.5   0.3]
MinAcceptableVal = [-0.5 -0.3]

simulatedReturnsEVT3 = [0.6 0.3; 0.3 0.3; 0.3 0.3; 0.3 0.4]
simulatedReturnsEVT3 = repmat(simulatedReturnsEVT3,[1 1 2])
data2                = [0.25 0.15; 0.25 0.15; 0.2 0.1]    
data2                = repmat(data2,[1 1 2])               

% Cut off Outliers
for i=1:2 
    for j=1:2 
        sliceEVT = simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j);
        sliceEVT(sliceEVT < MinAcceptableVal(i))=datasample (data2(:,i,j), 1,1,'Replace',false);
        sliceEVT(sliceEVT > MaxAcceptableVal(i))=datasample (data2(:,i,j), 1,1,'Replace',false);
        simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j) = sliceEVT;
    end
end
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem, it seems it is related to the usage of `datasample`.

In your code you use:

```
datasample (data2(:,i,j), 1,1,'Replace',false);
```

in this call, the first "`1`" defines the number of sample to be extracted that is "`1`".

In case more than one values have to be replaced in the `simulatedReturnsEVT3` matrix, all of them wil be replaced by the same, unique number extracted using `datasample`

Again, if I've understood the problem, you should call `datasample` by specifying the number "`n`" of values are needed to replace the "out of the bound" values in `simulatedReturnsEVT3`

```
datasample (data2(:,i,:), n,1,'Replace',false)
```

To test this solution I've modified the definition of `MaxAcceptableVal` in order to have "more" values "out of the bound" in `simulatedReturnsEVT3`:

```
MaxAcceptableVal = [0.5   0.2]
```

These are the values of `simulatedReturnsEVT3` before the replacement:

```
val(:,:,1) =

    0.6000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.4000

val(:,:,2) =

    0.6000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.3000
    0.3000    0.4000
```

These are the values after the replacement:

```
val(:,:,1) =

    0.2500    0.1500
    0.3000    0.1000
    0.3000    0.1500
    0.3000    0.1000

val(:,:,2) =

    0.2000    0.1000
    0.3000    0.1500
    0.3000    0.1500
    0.3000    0.1000
```

This is the updated code:

```
% Set Maximum Acceptable Levels for Positive and Negative Returns
% MaxAcceptableVal = [0.5   0.3]
MaxAcceptableVal = [0.5   0.2]
MinAcceptableVal = [-0.5 -0.3]

simulatedReturnsEVT3 = [0.6 0.3; 0.3 0.3; 0.3 0.3; 0.3 0.4]
simulatedReturnsEVT3 = repmat(simulatedReturnsEVT3,[1 1 2])
data2                = [0.2 0.1; 0.25 0.15; 0.25 0.15; 0.2 0.1]    
data2                = repmat(data2,[1 1 2])               

% Cut off Outliers
for i=1:2 
    for j=1:2 
        sliceEVT = simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j)
% Identify the index of the values to be replaced
        idx=find(sliceEVT < MinAcceptableVal(i))
% Evaluate how many values have to be replaced        
        n=length(idx)
% Extract and assign  the number from "data2"        
        sliceEVT(idx)=datasample (data2(:,i,j), n,1,'Replace',false)

% Identify the index of the values to be replaced
        idx=find(sliceEVT > MaxAcceptableVal(i))
% Evaluate how many values have to be replaced        
        n=length(idx)
% Extract and assign  the number from "data2"        
        sliceEVT(idx)=datasample (data2(:,i,j), n,1,'Replace',false)

        simulatedReturnsEVT3(:,i,j) = sliceEVT
    end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply il_raffa. I believe you have correctly identified my problem with the datasample function. However, when applying your code to my dataset, it still produces the same problem. I have now decided to moved on with my analysis and will leave this step out. Thanks again!